# How can I add or subtract a variable if it is in a different set of function?

Tags: c++

I've declared a variable in a function (int main) and then I create a statement in a function (void) when I manipulate that variable the value it have does not change a bit in a function (int main). How can I manipulate that variable if the statement that I did is in a different function?

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void shoppingList (int money, int userChoice)
{
   cout<<"1. Apples for 20$"
       <<"\n2. Oranges for 30$"
       <<"\n\nChoice: ";
   cin>>userChoice;

       if (userChoice == 1)
       {
           money = money - 20;
           cout<<"20$ had been deducted ";
           cout<<"\nMoney: "<<money<<endl;
       }
       if (userChoice == 2)
       {
           money = money - 30;
           cout<<"30$ had been deducted ";
           cout<<"\nMoney: "<<money<<endl;
       }
}

int main()
{
   int userChoice;
   int money = 500;
   while (true)
   {
       char choices[2];
       cout<<"Money: "<<money<<"\n\n"<<endl;
       cout<<"1. Draw some Numbers"
           <<"\n2. Exit"
           <<"\n\nChoice: ";
       cin>>choices;

       if (choices[0] == '1')
       {
           system ("CLS");
           shoppingList (money ,userChoice);
           system ("PAUSE");
           system ("CLS");
       }

       else if (choices[0] == '2')
       {
           return 0;
       }

       else if (choices[0] > '2' || choices[0] < '1')
       {
       cout<<"\nInvalid Input\nPLs try again"<<endl;
       system ("PAUSE");
       system ("CLS");
       }

       else
       {
       cout<<"\nInvalid Input\nPLs try again"<<endl;
       system ("PAUSE");
       system ("CLS");
       }
   }
}
```

And if there's another error or a way to enhance it plss tell me how. Thanks in advance

Comment: Each variables has a "scope" and only within its scope a variable is "visible". You can make such variables global or pass them to the function with reference/pointer.

Comment: Look(learn) about references (or even pointer)

Comment: Functions in C are pass by value, meaning that you copy the value and give it to the function. therefore, changes that you made with the latter is lost to the former. to modify the former, you have to pass by pointer or reference.

Comment: @ImaginePowers You need to pass the parameters by reference, not by value, otherwise their values are copied, and the changes are lost after leaving shoppingList(). Declare shoppingList() as `void shoppingList (int& money, int& userChoice)` (note the `&` characters), and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the few observations,

**Case 1:** In below snapshot `money` and `userChoice` in `shoppingList ()` has local scope, hence any changes in that variable won't reflect in calling methods.

```
void shoppingList (int money, int userChoice) { /* catch by value */
}
int main(void) {

    shoppingList (money ,userChoice);

    return 0;
}
```

*How can I manipulate that variable if the statement that I did is in a different function?* Use pass by **reference variable** instead of pass by value. For e.g

```
/* catch by references */
void shoppingList (int &money, int &userChoice) { /* this money is reference of money 
                                                    declared in main(), so any change
                                                    with money in this API will reflect
                                                    in main() */ 

}
int main(void) {
     shoppingList (money ,userChoice);
     return 0;
}
```

In above case, from `main()` function you are passing `money` & catching with **reference variable** i.e there is no new memory is created for `money` in the `shoppingList ()` i.e both having the same memory location, hence if you do any change with `money` and `userchoice` in `shoppingList()` methods will get reflect in `main()` functions.